# GitLab CI/CD Multiple runners

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

im not sure if this has already been indicated in the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#global-parameters) but i want to know if this is possible

i have 2 runners (1 for building, and 1 for deploying)
i have my .gitlab-ci.yml configured to run 2 jobs

job1 to build
job2 to deploy

but currently both jobs run in parallel.

what i need is for job2 to wait for job1.

is the above scenario possible?

here is my sample .gitlab-ci.yml

```
job1: 
  tags: 
    - test1
  script:
    - echo Starting test build
    - ./mvnw clean package -DskipTest
  before_script:
    - cd backend
    - chmod +x mvnw

job2: 
  tags: 
    - deploy
  script:
    - echo Deployment Test
  before_script:
    - echo Pre-Deployment scripts running
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define 'stages' for the jobs.

```
stages:
  - job1
  - job2

job1: 
  tags: 
    - test1
  script:
    - echo Starting test build
    - ./mvnw clean package -DskipTest
  before_script:
    - cd backend
    - chmod +x mvnw

job2: 
  tags: 
    - deploy
  script:
    - echo Deployment Test
  before_script:
    - echo Pre-Deployment scripts running
```

More details in the [documentation](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/07/29/the-basics-of-gitlab-ci/).

Comment: While this is technically correct, my answer regarding the use of "needs" allows more flexibility and potentially far more efficient pipelines in an example that scales beyond a couple of jobs. Gitlab is also having to reconcile the "stages" behavior with the desire of many user to be able to use a DAG for the job dependencies. The needs functionality has been implemented with this future goal in mind, which is another reason to consider using needs.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the ["needs"](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needs) keyword in combination with unique runner tags.

```
job1: 
  tags: 
    - test1
  script:
    - echo Starting test build
    - ./mvnw clean package -DskipTest
  before_script:
    - cd backend
    - chmod +x mvnw

job2: 
  tags: 
    - deploy
  script:
    - echo Deployment Test
  before_script:
    - echo Pre-Deployment scripts running
  needs: ["job1"]
```

This is the ideal solution as it bypasses the priority of stages and therefore can be used in combination with any [stages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#stage) you actually might have associated with your pipelines. This option allows more flexibility in more complex (including multi project/pipeline) configurations.